# Error SESSION PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un login con SESSION y no entiendo por que me sale el error:
Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projecte\pacientes.php on line 3

y luego abajo en el Bienvenido no me sale el usuario que ha iniciado sesión y no entiendo lo que puede estar pasando , Si alguien me puede ayudar le agradeceré muchisimo ya que estoy haciendo un proyecto con PHP y el tema de las SESSION no lo acabo de entender del todo

Os paso el código que tengo:

```
<?php
session_start();
$varsesion=$_SESSION['usuario'];


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estils.css">
  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Pràctica M09-UF1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bienvenido : <?php echo $varsesion ?> </h1>
  <a href='cerrarsesion.php'>Cerrar Sesión</a>

    <div id="container">   
    <div id="color">
    <div id="fotologo">
    <img src=img/fhes.png>
</div>
</div>
    

    <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Inici</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Qui som?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Historia</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Serveis 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Ginecologia</a>
      <a href="#">Consultes Externes</a>
      <a href="#">Traumatologia</a>
      <a href="#">Cirugia</a>
      <a href="#">Medicina Interna</a>
      <a href="#">Urgencies</a>
      <a href="#">Quiròfan</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
    <li><a href="#section5">Consultes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6">Contacte</a></li>

    </ul>
    
    <form action="crear.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="in_name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" name="in_cognom">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Dia Ingreso" name="in_dingres">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Motivo" name="in_motiu">
    <input type="submit" name="in_bot">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código donde se hace el logueo en tu página creo que habrás olvidado definir esta variable. Es decir:

```
//consulta en DB donde comprubas si hay un usuario con nombre $_POST['usuario'] y password $_POST['password']
```

Si la consulta devuelve un resultado, quiere decir que el usuario existe y ha escrito correctamente el password, entonces lo rediriges a la página que desees (supongo que a "pacientes.php"), pero antes de eso debes definir esa variable. Es decir, algo parecido a esto:

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = '...';
header("Location: ruta/.../pacientes.php");
die();
```